# Is there a way to retrigger a Pub/Sub notifications for Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a bucket with pub/sub configured for OBJECT_FINALIZE but our application missed some messages and now we want to resend the missing messages, is there any way to do this using the api or we need to recreate the message manually and publish to the same topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replay only some missing events. You can

- Either generate the event manually and publish them into PubSub
- Or upload the file again to allow the Google Cloud Storage to generate a new event on these files.